# Программа на Python которая озвучивает текст

Tags: python

Я хочу сделать так что бы озвучивался текст, но мне выдает ошибку, **что тут не так**?
[image: Ошибка]

Я и **PyAudio** скачал и все равно ничего не работает.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import webbrowser


def talk(words):
    print(words)
    os.system('say ' + words)


talk("Hi")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же не используете модуль `speech_recognition`, как он должен озвучивать?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def recognize_speech():
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()

    with mic as source:
        print("Speak:")
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    
    try:
        return recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        pass

input_text = recognize_speech()
print("You said: " + input_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример с быстрым озвучивание через Google API

```
import gtts 
from playsound import playsound 

def talk(string, language='en'):
    obj = gTTS(text=string, lang=language, slow=False)
    obj.save("audio.mp3")
    playsound("exam.mp3")
```

Если нужно автономно - библиотека `pyttsx3` в помощь.